# Textarea \n to <br> without escaping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am entering stuff in a textarea, and after I press a button, my JS takes the textarea input and puts it inside a div tag.

The problem is, when I enter a newline in the textarea, like so:

```
Hi

Goodbye
```

It comes out in the div as

```
Hi<br><br>Goodbye
```

When I use Firebug to inspect the actual HTML markup live, I see this in the div:

```
Hi&lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; Goodbye
```

This is a function I found that should replace the newlines with breaktags:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {   
var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '\<br \/>' : '\<br>';    
return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
}
```

Here is how I use it:

```
etext = $('#mytext').val();
etext = nl2br(etext,false);
$('#mydiv').text(etext);
```

However as you see, it is not working.

How can I do this? If you need more code, do let me know

Comment: "it is not working" - how so? What is it doing that you are not expecting. And, no, I can't see as you didn't show an example.

Comment: @Oded - The example is the first part in the post, the "<br><br>", after I used the nl2br function

Comment: @Oded - I am expecting the div to have newlines, but instead it has the actual break tags.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it will work if you do:

```
$('#mydiv').html(etext);
```

...or with no framework:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = etext;
```

The problem is that [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is automatically escaping your markup characters:

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), which replaces special characters
>   with their HTML entity equivalents (such as &lt; for <).

Comment: Its one of those "Aww, DOH!" moments.. ;)